# RESTful vs SOAP with BMS Device

Tags: rest

First of all I don't code, I'm a BMS engineer where I use products which inturn uses REST API.
For programming that controller I use REST service & give the port as 80 
Now I need to understand, how port 80(HTTP) and REST API works together and what difference is that with SOAP?

What in general RESTful service gives my controller? Please answer me in a layman language so that i can understand.

Answer (score 1):

A "web server" receives the requests by listening at a port. Default port for HTTP request is 80.

SOAP and REST differs mainly in below aspects.
  1)How a service gets discovered
  2)Data transfer format across the wire 
  3)How request processed and response generated

SOAP messages are always XML. REST messages can be in JSON,XML...many other formats also supported.

Making REST based requests easier compared to SOAP based requests since "SOAP clients" are heavy weight and need special
libraries. Rest clients are light weight and can be easily generated from any device.